# Can I run a function instead of routing on otherwise in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

As my question asks, I want to know if that is possible. Why I want this? I am required to keep the link when the request fails so I use states in my bootstrap template instead of templates for the error pages. Now I need to catch everything that isn't registered and I need to tell my main controller to change the state if the route is not found. I checked the documentation, of course but it hasn't enlightened me so please help me out here if you can.

```
    $httpProvider.otherwise(function () {
        // code here
    });
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This routing logic is not very easy to understand but I believe you should look at using route change events instead like `$routeChangeStart` and check your auth service there

Comment: been there my friend, been there back and forth. thing is no request shows up when the route i access is wrong, so i guess there is no failure

Comment: No idea what that means. What `request` are you referring to? `is no failure` ??  Show what you tried and suggest you re-write question and provide better description for problem statement

Comment: why not use `$routeProvider.otherwise`? If you are talking about `$http` requests failing then its another story..

Comment: "I am required to keep the link when the request fails" - Jonathan, 2015